the management of PWD and OLDPWD in the bash
I'm trying to make a simple version of bash, but I'm facing a random behavior when unsetting the variable PWD:
before unsetting the PWD variable:
user:~$ env | grep PWD
PWD=/nfs/homes/user
OLDPWD=/nfs/homes/user
user:~$ echo $PWD
/nfs/homes/user
user:~$ echo $OLDPWD
/nfs/homes/user

after unsetting PWD:
user:~$ unset PWD
user:~$ env | grep PWD
OLDPWD=/nfs/homes/user
user:~$ echo $PWD
user:~$ echo $OLDPWD
/nfs/homes/user

after changing the current working directory:
user:~$ cd Desktop/
user:~/Desktop$ env | grep PWD
user:~/Desktop$ echo $PWD
/nfs/homes/user/Desktop
user:~/Desktop$ echo $OLDPWD

after changing the cwd the second time:
user:~/Desktop$ cd dir/
user:~/Desktop/dir$ env | grep PWD
OLDPWD=/nfs/homes/user/Desktop
user:~/Desktop/dir$ echo $PWD
/nfs/homes/user/Desktop/dir
user:~/Desktop/dir$ echo $OLDPWD
/nfs/homes/user/Desktop

this behavior seems weird to me why does OLDPWD disappear and come again without me unsetting it manually, I would need to hard-code it to have the same behavior in my code but I don't like that, is there any logical explanation of what is happening under the hood and what should I do to reproduce the same behavior?

PWD became unexported when you unset it. Changing directory sets PWD as a local shell variable, but env will not show it unless it is exported.

A number of the shell’s environment variables lose their special properties if unset.

make a simple version of bash  : Do you mean that you are re-implementing a bash subset in C? If your "toy bash lookalike" shell does not behave in the way you like, shouldn't we then find the error in your C code?
